# Is it possible to execute a command relative to a Terminal shell script?

Tags: osx-lion

I have a Terminal shell script file `start.command` that I launch from finder with:

```
ls -l
```

The file is in `~/foo` but list `~`, can I get the path of it's containing dir. I'd like to launch an application that is in the same folder as the file when the user runs the `.command` but it seems like I would need the absolute path to the file for that to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming bash, you need to `cd` to the script's enclosing directory before running `ls`.

You can one-line it with this:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

`$0` is the script's relative path, i.e. whatever you used on the command line to invoke it. `dirname` strips the filename from the path.

`$()` is a value expansion to feed to `cd`, and the quotes are all necessary to handle things like spaces in paths.